# ListView choiceMode overridden after using with custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am having a `ListView` being set from custom adapter class. In my layout, I am setting `choiceMode` for the `ListView`.

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
```

However checkboxes aren't appearing on the `ListView`. Is it because the choiceMode behaviour is  now overridden by using a custom adapter? How do I set the `choiceMode` in such case?

**Update**:
Following is my adapter code:

```
public class ContanctAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactBean> {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<ContactBean> items;
    private int row;
    private ContactBean objBean;

    public ContanctAdapter(Activity act, int row, List<ContactBean> items) {
        super(act, row, items);

        this.activity = act;
        this.row = row;
        this.items = items;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
            return view;

        objBean = items.get(position);

        holder.tvname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
        holder.tvPhoneNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvphone);

        if (holder.tvname != null && null != objBean.getName()
                && objBean.getName().trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.tvname.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName()));
        }
        if (holder.tvPhoneNo != null && null != objBean.getPhoneNo()
                && objBean.getPhoneNo().trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.tvPhoneNo.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getPhoneNo()));
        }
        return view;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvname, tvPhoneNo;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check **createViewFromResource** method of your custom adapter, your problem there likely. Anyway you can get more help if you post yours adapter code (though standart UI part)

Comment: Please check updated question. Just to tell, I am doing nothing about choiceMode/ showing checkbox in adapter class.

Comment: So you using your custom ViewHolder widget as list item, so it should provide the checkbox itself.